# Asked to analyse a contradictory quote that I don't agree with

Tags: logic

I'm given a [quote](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/14821-what-you-re-supposed-to-do-when-you-don-t-like-a)

> If you don't like something, change it. If you can't change it, change your attitude".

The statement is to discuss how this idea was developed with respect to the two prescribed texts. My issue with this quote is that I think it is invalid and contradictory of itself. The first component of the quote:

> If you don't like something, change it.

This can generally be interpreted in a way such that it advocates empowerment and a less fatalistic view. It implies that an individual is within his means to change what he does not like. 
The second component of this quote:

> If you can't change it, change your attitude.

This statement clearly contradicts the first. It advocates an oppressed, fatalistic view due to the fact that it is telling the reader that things are just out of your control and you just have to blindlessly adopt the situation you do not like by changing your attitude and 'living with it' so to speak.

Can someone please argue against my interpretation so I can start with essay because it feels like surely I am interpreting this wrong.

Comment: The second statement is conditional: _If_ you can't change it. Confronted with something you are unable to change (let's say: It's raining) I hardly find it fatalistic to not do something about it. Doing something about it would be idiotic (and futile). If you should try to change your attitude towards it, is a hole different story, but I don't think it's self-contradictory.

Comment: Are usernames like OP's allowed here?

Comment: Consider: "If you want to go outside, open the door. If the door is locked, use the key." It's not that it's contradictory, it's just that the directions could alternatively be given the following way: "If you want to go outside and the door is open, just go, otherwise use the key." Your quote is worded the way it is because it just sounds better that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do a search for the quote, you'll see there's a key phrase missing from understanding the point of the text that immediately follows it:

> "Don't complain."

The point is that you shouldn't complain. If you there's something you don't like, don't complain about it, change it (or at least try to). If you can't change it (which, I read as: "If you've tried to change it an discover that you cannot..."), adjust your attitude.

This quote follows in the stoic tradition. See, for example, [Marcus Aurelius](http://www.american-buddha.com/meditations2.8th.htm):

> If you are distressed by anything external, the pain is not due to the  thing itself but to your own estimate of it; and this you have the power to revoke at any moment. If the cause of the trouble lies in your own character, set about reforming your principles; who is there to hinder you?  If it is the failure to take some apparently sound course of action that is vexing you, then why not take it, instead of fretting? 'Because there  is an insuperable obstacle in the way.' In that case, do not worry; the responsibility for inaction is not yours. 'But life is not worth living with this thing undone.' Why then, bid life a good-humored farewell; accepting the frustration gracefully, and dying like any other man whose actions have not been inhibited.

*Meditations, 8.47*

It is thus not a "[fatalistic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/)" sentiment - it is not saying all that we do is subject to fate, but that some things are, and that other things lie in our sphere of control.

Comment: Thanks, I was not provided with the missing key phrase, which I think is important to the prescribed texts.

Answer (score 0):

Your quote is based on the [Serenity Prayer](http://www.lords-prayer-words.com/famous_prayers/god_grant_me_the_serenity.html), which begins :-

```
God grant me the serenity 
To accept the things I cannot change;
Courage to change the things I can;
And wisdom to know the difference.
```

This is a somewhat nicer version than the quote you have been given, but you could analyse your given quote by cross-referencing the original.

Your quote fails mainly by its peremptory style, whereas the Serenity Prayer is aspirational.

As the original is quite self-explanatory I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any contradiction behind the quote, although it could be literally misunderstood as you have pointed: change it or accept as it is?

The first part is telling you to try to change it anyway and the second part is saying that if you fail, then just accept it. I don't think it's contradict because you as an ordinary person, can never change everything you want. Let's suppose you could, then what if another person, ordinary too, wanted it another way. Unless one of you is the god, otherwise you have to comply with the rule set by the god.

So the philosophy behind the quote, as far as I understand, is that the world is complicated, we should try our hard to change it if we don't like it (so called "Man proposes"). However, everything is subject to some rules set by the god (some is known to us, some is not), so we cannot necessarily make it every time. Therefore, if you fail, don't be depressed and just accept the reality (so called "God disposes").

To sum up, the whole sentence is telling a simple principle: Man proposes. God disposes.